# How can a file transfer go so quickly if the size of a packet cannot exceed 1500 bytes?

Tags: tcp, ip

When downloading a file from a Web Site, speeds of many megabytes per second can be acheived. If TCP needs to break up and individually send packets over 1500 bytes, then how are these speeds possible? Doesn't the client have to wait for every 1500 byte fragment which should take a while?

Thanks

Comment: If you -1 please tell me why. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Doesn't the client have to wait for every 1500 byte fragment which
>   should take a while

No. That's the magic of `TCP`, you don't have to `ACK` every segment, you can `ACK` once in a while. The server can push lots of segments before the client positively must acknowledge at least some.

TCP uses a concept called "windows". A sender can push data into a window, causing it to shrink. The receiver acknowledges data, causing the window to expand. If the receiver doesn't acknowledge data, the transfer grinds to a halt.

In modern TCP knowing when to acknowledge data is the gist of the protocol. Doing it too often or not often enough has enormous impacts on performance.